# Editing OpenCV source code

Tags: source-code, opencv

How would one go about editing either the C++ opencv functions and/or the python opencv functions in Ubuntu? Where is the source code located? For C++ how would one go about recompiling the source code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Ubuntu is primarily a binary package based distribution, the source code isn't "located" anywhere on your system unless you explicitly download it; either:

1. by enabling the appropriate source repositories, and then using `apt-get source` e.g.

   ```
   apt-get source opencv
   ```

   Note that this will download the source into the current directory - hence does not need `sudo` if you are downloading into a location within your home directory. It should also apply any relevant Ubuntu-specific patches such that the built code is equivalent to that of the corresponding binary package.
2. by  downloading a source tarball or checking out from the maintainer's `git` (or similar) source code repository. 
   Note that this may get you a more up-to-date version of the software;  however it also won't necessarily have been tested or patched for your current system.

In either case, you will likely need to install additional **build dependencies** before you are able to recompile the package from source, regardless  of any changes you may have made to it.